# Cleanest way to code "Custom Write Panels/Meta Boxes"?

Tags: custom-post-types, metabox, custom-write-panel

As with anything in Wordpress it seems there are 20 way to do something, but after several weeks of extensive searching I really haven't found more then a couple tutorials floating around that really mirror each other in writing conventions which always makes me a little uneasy when this is the way I learn so I wanted to make a post and ask you guys, the community, what you think?....

Even if you just have a favorite resource such as a tutorial on the web, that would be very useful. I feel Like Ive combed over them all, but often it seems like asking a specific group of experienced people typically renders better results so here I am.

*PS - Ive tried DeluxeBlogs class, and it worked fine, but at the moment what Im really trying to do is learn the most "correct" way to go about writing my own meta boxes from scratch.

Thanks, 
SB

----- **EDIT 1 : Example of one of my current meta boxes** -----

```
<?php
// Register Custom Post Type Meta Boxes -- Description Field
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'store_description_meta_box_add' );
function store_description_meta_box_add()
{
    add_meta_box( 'epr_store_description_meta_id', 'Product Description', 'store_description_meta_box_cb', 'epr_store', 'normal', 'high' );
}

function store_description_meta_box_cb( $post )
{
    $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    $textbox = isset( $values['meta_box_description_text'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['meta_box_description_text'][0] ) : '';
    wp_nonce_field( 'my_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' );
    ?>
        <textarea name="meta_box_description_text" id="meta_box_description_text" style="width:100%; height:100px;text-align:left;">
            <?php echo $textbox; ?>
        </textarea>
    <?php   
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'epr_description_meta_box_save' );
function epr_description_meta_box_save( $post_id )
{
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
    if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

    $allowed = array( 
        'a' => array( 
            'href' => array() 
        )
    );

    if( isset( $_POST['meta_box_description_text'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_box_description_text', wp_kses( $_POST['meta_box_description_text'], $allowed ) );
}
?>
```

----- **EDIT 2 : Example of how to remove indentation after saving w/ Chris' help** -----

```
<?php
// Register Custom Post Type Meta Boxes -- Description Field
add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', 'store_description_meta_box_add' );
function store_description_meta_box_add()
{
    add_meta_box( 'epr_store_description_meta_id', 'Product Description', 'store_description_meta_box_cb', 'epr_store', 'normal', 'high' );
}

function store_description_meta_box_cb( $post )
{
    $values = get_post_custom( $post->ID );
    $textbox = isset( $values['meta_box_description_text'] ) ? esc_attr( $values['meta_box_description_text'][0] ) : '';
    wp_nonce_field( 'my_meta_box_nonce', 'meta_box_nonce' );
    ?>
        <textarea name="meta_box_description_text" id="meta_box_description_text" style="width:100%; height:100px;text-align:left;"><?php echo esc_attr($textbox); ?></textarea>
    <?php   
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'epr_description_meta_box_save' );
function epr_description_meta_box_save( $post_id )
{
    if( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) return;
    if( !isset( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'] ) || !wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['meta_box_nonce'], 'my_meta_box_nonce' ) ) return;
    if( !current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

    $allowed = array( 
        'a' => array( 
            'href' => array() 
        )
    );

    if( isset( $_POST['meta_box_description_text'] ) )
        update_post_meta( $post_id, 'meta_box_description_text', wp_kses( $_POST['meta_box_description_text'], $allowed ) );
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a sort of "plugin library" that contains a [base class for meta boxes](https://github.com/chrisguitarguy/mrg-wordpress-store/blob/master/store-plugin/library/includes/meta-box-tools.php).  Basically all it contains are a bunch of methods that generate form fields and some tabbed navigation stuff that I do for meta boxes that contain a lot of stuff.  This just let's me more rapidly develop the meta box without having to worry about coding form fields for hours.

I'll use that as a parent class for a class that actually adds the meta boxes.  That class would look something like this:

```
<?php
class wpseMetaBox extends davispressMetaBoxTools
{
    function __construct()
    {
        add_action( 'add_meta_boxes', array( &$this, 'add_meta_box' ) );
        add_action( 'save_post', array( &$this, 'save' ), 10, 1 );
        add_action( 'load-edit.php', array( &$this, 'add_styles_scripts' ) );
        add_action( 'load-post-new.php', array( &$this, 'add_styles_scripts' ) );
    }

    function add_meta_box()
    {
        add_meta_box( 'some-metabox', 'Meta Box Title', array( &$this, 'meta_box_cb' ), 'post' );
    }

    function meta_box_cb( $post )
    {
        wp_nonce_field( 'wpse_nonce', 'wpse_nonce' );
        // add fields here
        $o = $this->textinput( '_some_id', 'Some Label', $post->ID );
        echo $this->form_table( $o );
        // etc.
    }

    function save( $post_id )
    {
        // verify we can do this
        if( ! isset( $_REQUEST['wpse_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_REQUEST['wpse_nonce'], 'wpse_nonce' ) ) return;
        if( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post' ) ) return;

        // save data
        if( isset( $_REQUEST['_some_id'] ) )
            update_post_meta( $post_id, '_some_id', esc_attr( $_REQUEST['_some_id'] ) );
    }

    function add_styles_scripts()
    {
        // check and see if we're on the post type with the meta box
        if( ( isset( $_REQUEST['post'] ) && 'post' == get_post_type( $_REQUEST['post'] ) ) || ( isset( $_REQUEST['post_type'] ) && 'post' == $_REQUEST['post_type'] ) ) 
        {
            add_action( 'admin_print_scripts', array( &$this, 'scripts' ) );
            add_action( 'admin_print_styles', array( &$this, 'styles' ) );
        }
    }

    function scripts()
    {
        // wp_enqueue_script here
    }

    function styles()
    {
        // wp_enqueue_style here
    }
}
```

The most painful part of creating a meta box is writing the actual meta box call back function that outputs all the contents. It takes the longest, and it seemed like that was the thing that could most easily be more abstracted.  So that's what I did.  Other people will probably have much different opinions.

All that said: sometimes meta boxes (and any other part of a plugin/theme) don't fit into the mold.  You have to know when to abandon the stuff that makes it easy in favor of what the situation demands.  Don't get locked into your tools just because you created them.

This [tutorial](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/plugins/how-to-create-custom-wordpress-writemeta-boxes/) might interest you as well. It doesn't have anything like the above, just a basic how to.

Comment: Thanks for the respsonse Chris. Ironic you cited that particular tutorial since that was the last one I decided to go with as a reference for my current meta boxes. It was well written and seemed to work fine however my saved meta data always seemed to do some weird things after following that tut. Namely, every time I re-opened custom post with that meta box the text from the saved meta data kept getting strangely indented further and further to the right, couldn't figure out why though.

Comment: Ha, I wrote that tutorial! Was your text in a textarea?  If so, you have to do `<textarea><?php echo esc_attr( $content ); ?></textarea>` on one line in your meta box call back.  Otherwise your code indents will keep getting added to the textarea's content.  That's just a off the top of my head guess, but I've run into the problem before.

Comment: Oh right on, Im glad I got the author himself! lol. Please check my original post, Ive updated it to show what my adapted version of your code looks like.

Comment: Your code looks good.  The indent thing is due the textarea weirdness I described above.  The only thing I'm doing different from the tutorial is creating everything within a class whose parent class has a lot of methods that make creating the meta box callback much less painful.

Comment: Thanks Chris - Ok, i tried `<?php echo esc_attr($textbox); ?>` but its still rendering the same results...Not sure if missed something in your example or if its something else all together??...Also, if you have the time - can you extrapolate a bit on how you would go about using the class you built? Thanks again for the help.

Comment: Right now your textarea is split over three lines.  Put it all on one line. There's not much more to extrapolate on for the class.  You just call the methods to create fields.  So if you wanted to echo out a textarea you'd call `echo $this->textarea( '_some_id', __( 'A Label' ), $post->ID );`

Comment: Hmm..so weird it would do that if its on separate lines. As a test I also removed `esc_attr();` and it still formatted the text correctly as long as it was all on one line. Thanks for the tip! (And the great tutorial by the way)...So for the class, do I just place that first in my functions and then when I need to add new meta boxes just add - `<?php echo $this->textarea( '_some_id', __( 'A Label' ), $post->ID ); ?>` with my own appropriate data? Just wanted to double check I understood.

Comment: Yup, exactly.  I'd strongly suggest you write your own (you're welcome to use mine, obviously), as you'll know everything inside out.

Comment: So glad you found me Chris - you made my day man, and thank you for the assistance!

Comment: Hey guys, just wanted to sprinkle on that esc_textarea() (since 3.1) is the way to go for escaping data inside of text areas.

Comment: @goto10 - are you referring to using `esc_textarea()` instead of `esc_attr()`?

Comment: @Mr.Brown - Yes. You want to use the appropriate escape function for the context of where you are outputting your data. esc_attr() is for attributes (but not always).esc_url() is for the href attribute, etc. http://wordpress.tv/2011/09/07/mark-jaquith-jon-cave-brad-williams-plugin-security-showdown/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not big on plugins when editing the theme function file is an option, but the More Fields plugin saves so much time, that I use that instead. It's quick, easy, and gives me a lot of options in creating different types of fields grouped in metaboxes that can be assigned to specific post types.