# Is there any way to have Featured Text, as opposed to Featured Image?

Tags: plugin-development, theme-development

I need to have Featured Text displayed on my category page, as well as a Featured Image. The Featured Text can not be in the Post at all (just as a Featured Image is not in the Post).

Does anybody know of a plugin that already does this? I've looked around a fair bit and can't seem to find anything.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use the excerpt for this, as this is exactly what custom excerpt is for. The (custom/manual) excerpt could have been named "featured text", because that is also what it is.

This excerpt is not to be confused with an automatic excerpt production. This excerpt will be drawn form the x first word of the content, when the manual excerpt is empty.

To find the excerpt text box, enable it under Screen options on the edit page.

The ensure your theme is actually displaying the excerpt on archive pages.

Comment: Read more about excerpts: http://codex.wordpress.org/Excerpt

Comment: Thanks, especially for telling me where the excerpt box is found.

Answer (score 9):

Unless you're already using it for something else, that sounds like what the excerpt is made for: http://codex.wordpress.org/Excerpt

Comment: Couldn't use excerpt, had to be text not in the post. Thanks though.

Comment: There's a separate box for the excerpt where you can enter custom text that doesn't have to be what's in the post.

Comment: I would suggest use of custom excerpts here as well. You will get all the benefits of built-in WordPress filters + it will save you the time of choosing the correct meta key each time you publish a post.

Comment: @sanjaypoyzer Why can't you use the excerpt field?

Comment: Ah, I see. I didn't realise that there was an additional, optional excerpt box. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0):

Use a custom field with key `featured_txt`, and display its content in the category loop with:

```
   <?php echo get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), 'featured_txt', true ); ?>
```

Comment: IMO, for better user interface, this could be placed in a custom meta box. Related Answers: [**`[1]`**](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/14455/12615) and [**`[2]`**](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/28899/12615)

Comment: Ah, thanks so much. This is exactly what I wanted to do. The meta box I might add in later for best practices and all, but for now just having the user add in the key manually is enough. Thanks again.

Comment: This sounds like re-inventing the wheel … there is **already** an excerpt box, which works independently of the post content!

Comment: I agree that the_excerpt() would probably do what you want, but if you prefer this custom field approach, my plugin http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/kia-subtitle/ will add a field that you can then use for featured text.